# FullCalendar make editable option view-specific

Tags: javascript, reactjs, calendar, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

Is there any way to change editable option depending on view?
I want to make it 'false' for month view and 'true' for week view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately no. As per the documentation, you can set [view-specific options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-specific-options).

e.g.

```
views: {
  timeGridWeek: {
    editable: true
  },
  dayGridMonth: {
    editable: false
  }
}
```

However, at the time of writing it appears that `editable` is not one of the options which is allowed to be specified per-view. It's not very clear from the documentation which options are and aren't supported in this way.

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/gOLWjmr - the option does not get applied.

Perhaps you can make a [feature request](https://fullcalendar.io/requesting-features) or even [contribute the necessary code yourself](https://fullcalendar.io/contributing).

Comment: I had the same problem and solved it with `eventDataTransform` method, 
checking current view with `calendar.view.type`
 and update the event accordingly.

Comment: @kl3sk It would no doubt be a benefit to the community if you were to share that solution in full as another Answer to this question :-)

Comment: thank you for your advice. It's done. Hope it's enough.

Answer (score 1):

To be more precise, I manage to solve the problem with [eventDataTransform](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDataTransform) (example with timeGridWeek view)

```
let calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
    eventDataTransform(event) {
        if (calendar.view.type === 'timeGridWeek') {
            event.editable = false
        }

       return event
    }
})
```

FYI: I use [eventSources](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventSources) as date event. I didn't try with plain events object.

If it may help